# Multiple tables - add new row

Tags: html, jquery

I have several little PHP tables under eachother:

The blue is one table and so on

[image]

I want to be able to add a new row to the table when clicking the green button with plus sign on it. But how to detect under with table the button was clicked so that the the new row will be added under that exact table?

Code for my table is like that:

```
<?php    
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT category_name FROM categories"); // using mysqli_query instead
                            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

                                echo "<table id='tbl' class='col-12'><th name='category' class='open-list bg-grey txt-xl pl-3'>".$res['category_name']."</th>
                               
                                <tr class='content-div row align-items-center'>
                                    <td class='col-8'><input name='product_name' type='text' class='p-3 border-0 text-left txt-xl'></td>
                                    <td class='col-2 p-0 txt-xl'><input name='quantity' type='text' value='1' class='w-50 border-0 p-0 txt-xl'><label class='txt-xl m-0 text-left'>tk</label></td>
                                    <td class='col-2' ><input class='mr-3' type='checkbox' name='check'></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type='button' class='add_another bg-success m-2 col-2 additem-btn shadow d-flex justify-content-center'><i class='txt-lg-icon bi bi-plus'></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>";
                        
                            }
                        ?>
                        </table>
```

so far i tried this:

```
$('document').ready(function() { $('.add_another').click(function() {
  $("#tbl").append('<tr><td><input name="product_name" type="text" class="pr-3 text-left txt-xl col-12 border-dark"></td><td><input class="mx-3" type="checkbox" name="check"></td></tr>');});})
```

It worked as far as adding a new row, but no matter under which table i clicked the add button it always only added a new row into the first table.

Table headers (the ones with the grey background) come from my mysql database and each header has a id as well. So maybe there is a way to use the id-s to detect where the button was clicked or is there some other ways to solve my problem?

EDIT:

I would also like toggle between opening and closing the content under the table headers by clicking on the header.

So far i have tried those:

```
$(".open-list" ).click(function() {$( ".content-div" ).toggle("");});

$(function() {
        $('.open-list').on("click",function() {
            $(".content-div").closest("tr").toggle("")
        });
})
```

They open and close all of them together, but i want to be able to open/close each table content separately.

Thank You!

Comment: You can do it by finding the parent table of the element that was clicked. The element that was clicked is available in `event.target`. Note also that you're generating invalid markup, since all your tables have the same id (ids should be unique).

Comment: You might want to look into https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: This does not seem to be a PHP issue. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] WITHOUT ANY PHP, Just rendered HTML and Script

Comment: Also IDs must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs need to be unique

If you want to add the row AFTER the button, try this

`$(this).closest("tr").after()`

or

`$(this).closest("tbody").append()`

if AFTER the row with the button use

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add_another').on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").before('<tr><td><input name="product_name" type="text" class="pr-3 text-left txt-xl col-12 border-dark"></td><td><input class="mx-3" type="checkbox" name="check"></td></tr>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='col-12'>
  <th name='category' class='open-list bg-grey txt-xl pl-3'>Whatever</th>

  <tr class='row align-items-center'>
    <td class='col-8'><input name='product_name' type='text' class='p-3 border-0 text-left txt-xl'></td>
    <td class='col-2 p-0 txt-xl'><input name='quantity' type='text' value='1' class='w-50 border-0 p-0 txt-xl'><label class='txt-xl m-0 text-left'>tk</label></td>
    <td class='col-2'><input class='mr-3' type='checkbox' name='check'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type='button' class='add_another bg-success m-2 col-2 additem-btn shadow d-flex justify-content-center'><i class='txt-lg-icon bi bi-plus'></i>Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
<table class='col-12'>
  <th name='category' class='open-list bg-grey txt-xl pl-3'>Whatever</th>

  <tr class='row align-items-center'>
    <td class='col-8'><input name='product_name' type='text' class='p-3 border-0 text-left txt-xl'></td>
    <td class='col-2 p-0 txt-xl'><input name='quantity' type='text' value='1' class='w-50 border-0 p-0 txt-xl'><label class='txt-xl m-0 text-left'>tk</label></td>
    <td class='col-2'><input class='mr-3' type='checkbox' name='check'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type='button' class='add_another bg-success m-2 col-2 additem-btn shadow d-flex justify-content-center'><i class='txt-lg-icon bi bi-plus'></i>Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `id`, you can use `this` operator and find the parent of `table` to add a new row like below.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.add_another').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('table').append('<tr><td><input name="product_name" type="text" class="pr-3 text-left txt-xl col-12 border-dark"></td><td><input class="mx-3" type="checkbox" name="check"></td></tr>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl' class='col-12'>
  <th name='category' class='open-list bg-grey txt-xl pl-3'>one</th>

  <tr class='row align-items-center'>
    <td class='col-8'><input name='product_name' type='text' class='p-3 border-0 text-left txt-xl'></td>
    <td class='col-2 p-0 txt-xl'><input name='quantity' type='text' value='1' class='w-50 border-0 p-0 txt-xl'><label class='txt-xl m-0 text-left'>tk</label></td>
    <td class='col-2'><input class='mr-3' type='checkbox' name='check'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type='button' class='add_another bg-success m-2 col-2 additem-btn shadow d-flex justify-content-center'><i class='txt-lg-icon bi bi-plus'></i>Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id='tb2' class='col-12'>
  <th name='category' class='open-list bg-grey txt-xl pl-3'>one</th>

  <tr class='row align-items-center'>
    <td class='col-8'><input name='product_name' type='text' class='p-3 border-0 text-left txt-xl'></td>
    <td class='col-2 p-0 txt-xl'><input name='quantity' type='text' value='1' class='w-50 border-0 p-0 txt-xl'><label class='txt-xl m-0 text-left'>tk</label></td>
    <td class='col-2'><input class='mr-3' type='checkbox' name='check'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type='button' class='add_another bg-success m-2 col-2 additem-btn shadow d-flex justify-content-center'><i class='txt-lg-icon bi bi-plus'></i>Add</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```